# How to make keypress select in drop down using Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a drop down where the item size is large so I am looking for a way to enable keyboard-input (key press) so that I can type and it automatically moves to that option in the drop down. Any suggestions?

```html
<ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" style="max-height: 150px; overflow-y: auto; max-width : 10px">
  <li ng-repeat="value in feature.values | unknownValueFilter | featureValueOrder ">
    <a ng-click="currentValue.set(value)" href="">
      {{value | featureValueFormatter }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Id recommend setting up a fiddle, be happy to take a look at it then.

Comment: Are you basically looking for an incremental search like http://codepen.io/hiisi13/pen/IfrDE or http://embed.plnkr.co/EAMPqJ/ ? Neither of which are my work by the way.

Comment: @alphapilgrim https://plnkr.co/edit/9rpuHzlZ1gSMd3fHHxHP?p=preview Tried the suggestion given by GPost but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use `filter` on `<li>` in conjunction with `ng-keyup` on `<ul>` for example.

```
<ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" style="max-height: 150px; overflow-y: auto; max-width : 10px" ng-keyup="onKeyUp($event)">
  <li ng-repeat="value in feature.values | filter: tappedKeys | unknownValueFilter | featureValueOrder ">
    <a ng-click="currentValue.set(value)" href="">
      {{value | featureValueFormatter }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And add in your controller:

```
$scope.tappedKeys = '';

$scope.onKeyUp = (e)=>{
  $scope.tappedKeys += e.key;
};
```

But you should think on how to clear typed value.

However in any case I would suggest you to decrease your list someway or create visible filter (text input maybe). Otherwise user will barely understand such behavior.

Comment: @GPost : I tried like you mentioned but not seeing it happens.

Comment: @GPost : https://plnkr.co/edit/9rpuHzlZ1gSMd3fHHxHP?p=preview but still its not working

Comment: You have to use `ng-repeat` on `<li>` node and use `filter` on it to see some effect

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks :) but once I select when I try to select again the options are resetting back. Can you suggest me a way to clear up ? I am new to angular. Would much appreciate if you let me know what should I use to clear the pressed keys

Comment: @user3407267, my suggestion is in looking for another way:) It's better for user to see the filter. Otherwise you may try to use `$timeout()` in `onKeyUp()` callback, in which you will set early defined variable to true `clearFlag = true`. Then each time you're in `onKeyUp()` check for the flag: `if (clearFlag === true) {$scope.tappedKeys = ''}`. Figure out others steps by yourself=)

Comment: Thanks :) How about if I get the count of key pressed when count > 1  if do {$scope.tappedKeys = ''} basically resetting after every search ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use `ng-model` and apply it as a `filter` in `ng-repeat`. Rest is done automatically by angularjs.

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Search" />
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in all_items | filter: searchString">
        <a href="" ng-click="blabla(item.key)">{{item.val}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```